# Avoid a second iteration in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've created a QuerySet in a view.  I need to do something to one of the fields (parse it in to a dictionary, to be exact).  So, I iterate through the QuerySet to do my parsing.  Then, I take my new object (whatever it's going to be), and pass it to the template.  Then, the template has to iterate through the object... Essentially 2 iterations of the same information.

Here's my view code:

```
t = Transaction.objects.values()
for r in t:
    r['data'] = dict([z.split(':',1) for z in r['data'].split('|')])
```

...Of course, I pass the new and improved 't' to the template, where something like this happens:

```
{% for r in t %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ r.username }}</td><td>{{ r.source }}</td><td>{{ r.trans }}</td><td>{{ r.transtime }}</td>
    <td>
    {% for k,v in r.data.items %}
        {{ k }}: {{v}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In the old-school days of spaghetti code, this wouldn't be an issue.  I'd just loop through the data, and for each record I'd parse out and display what I needed...

So here's my question:  In django-world, how do I avoid looping through my data twice?  Is this "OK" in Python-world, or is there a better way?  Thanks!

Comment: It'll be much easier to help you if we can see some code.

Comment: Sorry guys, not much code yet :-)  I'll edit my post when I have some more details  Thanks!

Comment: OK, code is in the original post now.  Thanks!

Comment: What your doing looks perfectly fine.  You're only hitting the database once, and unless you hit performance issues (which you shouldn't), I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @sdolan:  Thanks. Just needed someone to pat me on the shoulder and tell me everything's gonna be OK.  Appreciate you looking at it.

Comment: You could put the post processing on the model class in a method called something like `get_data_dict` and use that in the template, and remove it from the view.  It really depends if it's a "one off" processing for that particular view, or if you'd like to use it elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to really understand what you need without a more concrete example of what you are doing, but generally one would solve this by passing the view that queryset object wrapped in a generator for deferred processing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing necessarily "wrong" with looping through the same iterable twice. Sometimes, that may be necessary, and without example code, there's no way to say whether it is or not.

What does matter is that it's not actually querying the database twice. Django caches querysets, but the way you interact with it sometimes can cause additional queries on top of that. Again, though, without example code, I can't say whether you have a problem with that or not.

**UPDATE** There's nothing wrong with what you've done, if there's additional processing needed on the queryset, the right place to do that is in the view. Looping over the new and improved version in the template is not a problem, and the database is not being hit with redundant queries. I say stop worrying so much ;)